# How to copy an audio file to a removable SD card using SAF

Tags: android, audio, inputstream, storage-access-framework

I want to copy an audio file to a removable sd card on Android. I have read and tried the Storage Access Framework(SAF) and am able to write a text successfully. Unfortunately when I follow the same approach to write an audio file say a .mp3, it creates an empty file and no exceptions are thrown either.

I get the path to the destination directory this way:

```
Intent intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE)
startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode)
```

And in the onActivityResult this is how I attempt to copy the file:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent resultData) {
//Checking requestCode and reslutCode removed for brevity
Context context = this;
Uri treeUri = resultData.getData();
String newAudioFile = "newAudioFile.mp3";
DocumentFile pickedDir = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(context, treeUri);
String extension = newAudioFile.substring(newAudioFile.lastIndexOf('.')+1,newAudioFile.length());
String srcFilePath = "/storage/emulated/0/Downloads/beat.mp3";

try {
  DocumentFile newFile = pickedDir.createFile("audio/"+extension, newAudioFile);
  OutputStream out = context.getContentResolver().openOutputStream(newFile.getUri());
  InputStream in = new FileInputStream(srcFilePath);
File srcFile = new File(srcFilePath);
  Log.d("srcFile " + srcFile.exists());// returns true
  Log.d("!srcFile.isDirectory() " + !srcFile.isDirectory());// returns true

  byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];//new byte[in.available()] gave same results
  int read;
//in.read(buffer) below returns -1
//from the docs that means "no byte is available because the stream is at the end of the file"
  while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    out.write(buffer, 0, read);
  }
  in.close();
  // write the output file (You have now copied the file)
  out.flush();
  out.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
  Log.d("Exception " + e);
}
}
```

When I use this to get the byteArray, the length is 0 hence no bytes are returned i.e. in.read(buffer) returns 0

```
public byte[] inputStreamToByteArray(InputStream inStream) throws IOException {
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int bytesRead;
while ((bytesRead = inStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    baos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

I am testing on a real device with API 22. Application's configs:

`minSdkVersion 21
 targetSdkVersion 25`

I need some help as I've run out of options now. Thanks.

Here is a [link](https://github.com/gafful/android-audio-inputstream) to a sample project for the problem.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143313/discussion-on-question-by-godfred-how-to-copy-an-audio-file-to-a-removable-sd-ca).

Comment: O again you. Nothing better to do?